# Sumifs with multiple or relationship

Tags: excel, countif

I want to count a number lines with multiple criteria (and/or relationship). 
To be concrete:
I have 3 columns Standard (Y/N), FTE number (number), and the Maturity (low, medium high)
Now I would like to count all lines that fullfill the following criteria:

```
Standard =N AND
FTE number = 1 OR
and maturity =low
```

So far I know that the following  exits for a or relationship

```
   =countifs(criteriarange (Nr of lines), {criteria 1 (=1 FTE) , criteria 2 (=low)})
```

But this will not allow me to build a or relationship between criteria ranges. I would like to have a or relationship between 2 criteria ranges. meaning between the range maturity and the range FTE (overlapping range).

The And relationship (standard = Y) is then easily added in the formular with a third range.

Is that somehow posssible?

Many thanks
Julia

Comment: is it `(X AND Y) OR Z` or is it `X AND (Y OR Z)`?

Comment: @ScottCraner, normally, **AND** takes preference on the **OR**, so it is evaluated first. As for the question, there is an `AND` function that evaluates several conditions and returns TRUE or FALSE. I don't know if this can be used with ranges though.

Comment: @FDavidov I will let the OP tell us how the logic is desired and not assume.  They are two very different statements and are attacked in two different ways.  I have an answer for either, depending on what the OP wants.  It is the same as `(2*2)+2` and `2*(2+2)`.

Comment: Oops!!!! Now I see the `OR AND MATURITY`. IN any case, if you have `A OR B AND C` it is normally (all languages I know) equivalent to `A OR (B AND C)`.

Comment: @FDavidov I agree that mathematically the correct method is to do the the multiplication first.  But I want the OP to clarify before posting an incorrect answer.

Comment: Agree. Let's wait....